# android keyboard not adjust/pan working android:windowSoftInputMode=

Tags: android, keyboard, android-manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.jony.ViewMessages"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustUnspecified"                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        </activity>
```

Adjust Pan or resize is not working and it is hiding all my text view and that I don't want. Here is another post that declares it a bug.
[See This related post please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558810/adjustpan-not-preventing-keyboard-from-covering-edittext)

Answer (score -1):

just try this

```
<activity android:name="com.jony.ViewMessages"
          android:label="@string/app_name" 
          android:screenOrientation="landscape"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</activity>
```

Comment: not working :( I am trying it on Android 2.1-update-1 Sony Ericsson X10i

Comment: Due to the Fullscreen portion of the theme `windowSoftInputMode` is completely ignored. Take a look at `LEO`'s answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible