# Android Keyboard that doesn't squeeze layout but shift EditText

Tags: android, keyboard, cordova

I have developed an iPhone app and now going to port it to Android. Almost all features work but the only thing I noticed is when I focus any Texbox or Textarea, the keyboard is opened and moves the whole page off the screen. I got to know that putting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` would solve the issue but then another issue came out.

Now when I focus any text element, the keyboard is opened but the view size is squeezed to the height (minus keyboard height) shifting bottom tab buttons above keyboard which is very bad effect in my opinion. Although it doesn't now move the whole page off the screen but can I use this property `android:windowSoftInputMode="..."` to ask it to show keyboard over tab buttons (hiding tab buttons under keyboard) but just move the view if the text elements are being hidden?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible

Comment: there is no XML layout. I am talking about WebView and html way or resizing upon keyboard shown.