# Page scroll when soft keyboard popped up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-scrollview, android-keypad

I have a `<ScrollView>` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_one"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number" >

         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_two"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number" >

         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_three"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number" >

          <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok_btn"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/ok_str" />

      </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As you see above, the simple layout consists of three input fields and an "Ok" button.

I run my app with the above layout, when I tap on the 1st input field (`@+id/input_one`), the soft keyboard will pop up from the bottom of the screen, it **hides** the 3rd input field and the "Ok" button.

Since I use `<ScrollView>` , I thought I can scroll the page up in order to see the 3rd input field and "Ok" button which are **hidden** by the soft keyboard, **but the page is not scrollable**. Why? How to get rid of it? **basically, i would like to see every input fields and "Ok" button even the soft keyboard popped up.**

Comment: remove the <ScrollView>, LinearLayout should be your outer layout, it will work, i hope even if the sofkeyboard pop up .

Comment: @pakshaheen That won't fix the problem when scrollview is required.

Comment: here is the working code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible/44242034#44242034

Answer (score 136):

I fixed the problem by defining the following attribute in `<activity>` of **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: You don't need stateVisible. That will make the soft keyboard appear when the app is launched even when the user is not focused on a EditText

Comment: it's autometically open keyboard even there is not edittext

Answer (score 39):

Ok, I have searched several hours now to find the problem, and I found it.

None of the changes like `fillViewport="true"` or `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` helped me.

I use Android 4.4 and this is the *big mistake*:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Somehow, the Fullscreen themes prevent the ScrollViews from scrolling when the SoftKeyboard is visible.

At the moment, I ended up using this instead:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar
```

I don't know how to get rid of the top system bar with time and battery display, but at least I got the problem.

Hope this helps others who have the same problem.

**EDIT:** I got a little workaround for my case, so I posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859474/scrollview-not-working-when-keyboard-is-showing-in-android/22067230#22067230):

I am not sure if this will work for you, but it will definitely help you in understanding, and clear some things up.

**EDIT2:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible) is another good topic that will help you to go in the right direction or even solve your problem.

Comment: +1 In my case the status bar was hidden by a 3rd party lib in code:             `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Comment: @qweret What if I need both of them? Full screen and scrolling.

Comment: @Prabs Did you find any solution? I also want both Full Screen and scrolling.

Comment: @Johny Nope. For now I'm using full screen for entire app except that activity with scrolling3.

Comment: @Prabs The only solution I thought is have transparent status bar but in my case is stil an issue because I want to support API >= 16 . Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 20):

For me the only thing that works is put in the activity in the manifest this atribute:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

To not show the keyboard when opening the activity and don't overlap the bottom of the view.

Answer (score 14):

put this inside your Manifest like this in No fullscreen Mode

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

in your manifest

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
    android:name="com.example.patronusgps.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I've tried this but unfrotunately, no luck at all... However, the root view is **not** a `ScrollView`, but a `RelativeLayout` which contains a `LinearLayout` which then contains a `ScrollView`

Answer (score 11):

In your `Manifest` define `windowSoftInputMode` property:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
```

Comment: @JacobRas please check this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowSoftInputMode  it has the value "adjustNothing" :)

Comment: I have the same trouble, but scrollview doesn't work with adjustNothing :(

Answer (score 7):

check out this.

```
<activity android:name=".Calculator"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the following code to solve your problem:

```
 <activity
     android:name=".DonateNow"
     android:label="@string/title_activity_donate_now"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan">
 </activity>
```

Comment: You should bother explaining what your code does instead of just posting a dry piece code as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This only worked for me:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 2):

Also if you want to do that **programmatically** just add the below line to the onCreate of the activity.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE );
```

Answer (score 0):

well, the simplest answer I tried is just removing your code which makes the activity go full screen. I had a code like this which was responsible for making my activity go fullscreen :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

    getWindow().setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
    );
}
```

I just removed my code and it works completely fine although if you want to achieve this with your fullscreen on then you'll have to try some other methods