# BottomBar Moves With Keyboard (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-tablelayout

I have this code:

```
 <TableLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
        android:id="@+id/table1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"

            android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Search"

            />
        <TableRow

            android:id="@+id/tableRowFive"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/arrow"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxWidth="40dp"
                android:maxHeight="40dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:text="Click To View"
                android:textSize="26dp"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/arrow2"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxWidth="40dp"
                android:maxHeight="40dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                />
        </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Whenever I click on the EditText part of my TableLayout, The keyboard pops up just as usual, but the TableLayout goes on top with it. I want the TableLayout to stay on the bottom and not follow with the keyboard.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410257/layout-of-the-screen-moves-up-when-keyboard-is-displayed

Comment: Is this your complete layout?

Comment: Yes... It is....

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest add this to the activity:

```
<application ... >
  <activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" ... >
    ...
  </activity>
...
</application>
```

The logic behind is:

adjustResize = resize the page content

adjustPan = move page content without resizing page content

Comment: That doesn't do anything.

Comment: Do you have a code in the activity or fragment that do adjustResize or adjustPan?