# Header causing scrollview to not scroll to edit text when keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

What I would like is when a user clicks on one of the edit texts for the screen to resize and scroll up so the it focuses on the that edit text.

The manifest is setup for adjust resize:

```
  <activity
     android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/AppThemes"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"/>
```

The XML layout for the login screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/main_background" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!--<LinearLayout-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/login_header"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:paddingTop="30dp"-->
                <!--android:paddingBottom="30dp"-->
                <!--android:gravity="center_horizontal"-->
                <!--android:orientation="vertical">-->

                <!--<ImageView-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/login_fragment_logo"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="120dp"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="120dp"-->
                    <!--android:src="@drawable/logo_with_dropshadow" />-->

                <!--<TextView-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/login_fragment_app_title"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_margin="5dp"-->
                    <!--android:text="@string/digital_door_viewer"-->
                    <!--android:textAllCaps="true"-->
                    <!--android:textSize="18sp" />-->

            <!--</LinearLayout>-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/login_fragment_email_edit_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/login_fragment_password_edit_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_fragment_register_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:minHeight="0dp"
                    android:text="@string/register"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_fragment_forgot_password"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:minHeight="0dp"
                    android:text="@string/forgot_your_password"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@drawable/yellow_selector"
                    android:minHeight="0dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                    android:paddingTop="7dp"
                    android:text="@string/login"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What's going wrong is when I uncommented the header for the screen, it doesn't scroll up but with it commented out it works as intended...what am I missing?

Comment: I saw your site. You're all rounder. ha in all the fields.

Comment: :) try to be at least

Comment: Keep it up....and how can i download your songs???

Comment: send me a github issue and I'll toss up a download https://github.com/isuPatches/RockThePatch

Comment: Can you post the code for your edit text?

Comment: Right now it's purely that xml..there's nothing in the Fragment/Activity tapping into those views until I get the scrolling behavior correct

Answer (score 0):

Try scrolling to the view:

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
int[] coordinates = new int[2];
editText.getLocationOnScreen(coordinates);
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(coordinates[0],coordinates[1]);
```

Comment: I've tried that a few times...the issue I'm finding with that route is that it doesn't scroll the first time when the keyboard first pops up

Comment: @isuPatches - are you using full screen mode?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859474/scrollview-not-working-when-keyboard-is-showing-in-android/22067230#22067230

Comment: So my app theme inherits from  `<style name="AppThemes" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`  and I tried playing around with flags and still not getting the desired behavior  `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>`  I'm thinking it's related to the scollview not being scrollable at the time the keyboard appears because subsequent calls work.  I'm doing the scroll calls in the OnClick of the views because I couldn't think of a better place to put them

Comment: So I tried a few things and what did work is adding a postDelayed of 1700-2000ms and then scrolling.  the issue seems to be as the keyboard is opening the scroll won't work but when it is open it's fine.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around a way to dynamically wait for that to happen.