# scrollview not scrolling to bottom of the screen

Tags: android, scrollview, fullscreen

I have a difficulty with implementing scroll view while using Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen.
When the user opens the application and click on editText the keyboard opens but the user cannot scroll beneath the edittext.
After many attempts I figured it something to do with the theme I am using (fullscreen) 
This is my code .xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:fillViewport="true"
 >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vieww"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1000dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/test_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/vieww" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/test_edit"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When the keyboard is opened the user cannot see the lowest view beneath the edittext.

What I tried so far:

1. I played a lot with windowSoftInputMode of the activity I tried combination of adjustResize/adjustPan but nothing seems to work.
2. I tried to change the container to LinearLayout but it still not working for me
3. I found a solution here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859474/scrollview-not-working-when-keyboard-is-showing-in-android)
   The problem with this solution I need to change the minSdk to 19, when the application starts I can see black stripe where has been the title bar.
   the other issue is when the user open the keyboard by pressing on edittext the title bar returns

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the ScrollView in a Relative Layout, so you can fit the size, if the keyboard appears.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/vieww"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1000dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/test_edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/vieww" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/test_edit"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```