# How do I allow scrolling in Xamarin.Android (Xamarin.Forms) when the softkeyboard overlays part of the content?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Forms activity. I have wrapped scrollview around my content via:

```
<ScrollView
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    VerticalOptions="Center">
```

When the natural height of the activity is higher then the display size, this allows scrolling. On the other hand, when the user clicks in a textbox and the soft keybaord pops up the user can't scroll to see what's behind the softkeyboard which is a problem.

Following a [question for native android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9989782/25282) I added in my style file:

```
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateVisible|adjustResize</item>
    ...
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't give me my desired scrolling behavior when the soft-keyboard is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that, but this one is most in Xamarin spirit:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `WindowSoftInputMode` in your **MainActivity.cs**.

**This is how you can do it**

```
[Activity(Label = "MyActivity", Theme = "@style/CustomTheme", WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize)]
```

Or put below line in **OnCreate()** method of **MainActivity**.

```
Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize);
```

Comment: It seems obvious to me how to do this if I have a straight Xamarin.Android activity. Unfortunately, it isn't clear to me how to do it with the Forms activity. Where do I put this?

Comment: Just put this line in the **MainActivity**.

Comment: I put it into my MainActivity right before that calls `LoadApplication(new App());`. Unfortunately, it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"` to your scroll view and try. I have the same scenario. I have not set anything and it works fine with soft input. It manages by OS i guess.