# Recyclerview and Cardview I have design problems

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

[image]> I'm using Recyclerview. The page slides up when I click on EditText. How to fix this.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989130/page-scroll-when-soft-keyboard-popped-up) ?

Comment: Could you add the `layout` resource file with the `recycler-view`

Comment: thank you i problem solved.  @NileshPanchal

Comment: welcome @Sezer Türkdal

Comment: add this code in AndrodiManifest.xml **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"**
in activity tag

Comment: in **menifest.xml** add this line in activity tag **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"**

Answer (score 1):

Please use

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Inside manifest file

Answer (score 0):

**- Add Following Code Into AndroidManifest.xml With Specific Activity.**

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```