# android keyboard is hiding the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I have a relative layout that is supposed to move up when the soft keyboard opens. It worked all fine until I had to make the application full screen. After I set

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

the layout doesn't move up. It stays where it is and the keyboard is on top of it.
I tried with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I found my answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. The answer to this question can be found here:

[Android How to adjust layout in Full Screen Mode when softkeyboard is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible)