# Detect soft input visibility and height when using fullscreen mode

Tags: android, android-layout

I've read multiple posts of this issue and the solution was to use `OnGlobalLayoutListener`. Problem here is that my application has declared following in manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

So the inputmode adjust doesn't work and I cant use `OnGlobalLayoutListener`

How to get the event that soft input is visible/gone, and I would also need to get the height of input as well to adjust my current layout `bottomMargin`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you use `OnGlobalLayoutListener` but it works fine in my code below:

```
        final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.container);
        final ViewTreeObserver observer = activityRootView
                .getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                Rect r = new Rect();
                // r will be populated with the coordinates of your view
                // that area still visible.
                activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight()
                        - (r.bottom - r.top);
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, String.valueOf(heightDiff),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

THe above code is in `onResume()` of my TestActivity with the theme `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`

layout file for the view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="aaa" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The activity config in menifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activity.TestActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Can you post the xml also, my application has only one Activity and everything else are Fragments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible

This clearly states that it doesn't work and there are also bugs for Google about it.

Comment: And due to that post this seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: @Niko I don't know whether I've misunderstood you, but take a look at my xml

Comment: Worked for me on API19 with the following flags enabled:  `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN`, `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION`, `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY`, `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE` (required for us, should not affect this answer), and `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` (required for us, should not affect this answer). We actually use this to reapply the two View flags after the soft keyboard is hidden (otherwise the navigation remains visible).

Answer (score 0):

I use this for detecting visibilty of softInput. Try this :

```
public boolean isKeyBoardVisible;
    int previousHeightDiffrence = 0;

    public void checkKeyboardHeight(final View parentLayout) {

        parentLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {

                        Rect r = new Rect();
                        parentLayout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                        int screenHeight = parentLayout.getRootView()
                                .getHeight();
                        int heightDifference = screenHeight - (r.bottom);

                        if (previousHeightDiffrence - heightDifference > 50) {

                            // Keyboard is not visible
                        }
                        if (previousHeightDiffrence - heightDifference < -50) {

                            // Keyboard Visible
                        }

                        previousHeightDiffrence = heightDifference;
                        if (heightDifference > 100) {

                            isKeyBoardVisible = true;

                        } else {

                            isKeyBoardVisible = false;

                        }

                    }
                });

    }
```

here parentLayout is top most layout of my activity and heightDifference is height of my keyboard if keyboard is Visible.....

Comment: Not working atleast with my api level which is 8. And Dianne Hackborn posted answer to this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/android-developers/T193nVgXDSA/O6UZmDqskFYJ -> It cannot work.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was about full screen mode only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <MyView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then Implement the MyView

```
public class MyView extends View
{
     public static int ScreenHeight;

     @Override
     public function onDraw(Canvas canvas){
          if(ScreenHeight != canvas.getHeight()){
              // this is your event
          } 
          ScreenHeight = canvas.getHeight();

     }
}
```

Now `ScreenHeight` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well this has absolutely nothing to do with my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible this has the same issue. Window doesn't resize it's content so screen height remains the same.