# Keyboard hiding EditText when android:windowTranslucentStatus=true

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-4.4-kitkat

We're applying the new Android KitKat translucent theme in our apps, and we're getting a weird issue when the keyboard appears. If we don't use the new `android:windowTranslucentStatus` attribute, all works as usual: The screen is resized, and all remains visible. But when we're using `android:windowTranslucentStatus`, the screen isn't resized and our `EditText` becomes hidden by the keyboard.

A sample of the issue:
[image: http://fewlaps.com/xtra/quitnowStackoverflow.png]

The only difference between the screens is in the attribute in the style:

First screen:
`<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>`

Second screen:
`<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`

We think this is a bug from Kitkat release, but we want you to be aware of this. We're getting a little mad. Of course, if someone have a solution, it will be amazing.

EDIT: I just added this issue to the Android issue tracker. Probably you'll be interested in starring the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36986276

Comment: Thanks @antimo for posting the image and formatting the whole question :)

Comment: Have you tried setting the [fitsSystemWindows](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fitsSystemWindows) to true?

Comment: Yes, we tried setting it in the EditText and in its container, too. But we haven't too luck.

Comment: You can try to put the `fitSystemWindows` attr in the root layout of this `Activity`. It works for me

Answer (score 7):

I also ran into this very annoying issue. But eventually I got this working:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Instead of setting fitSystemWindows="true" in the theme, I set it on the root view of my layout..

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I also use the great [SystemBarTintManager](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint) in my activity:

```
new SystemBarTintManager(this).setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
```

This seems to work well, but admittedly seems pretty fickle. Hope it helps someone anyway!

Comment: Thanks @DanielGrech!

I've also tryed what you mention, creating a root Layout with the fitsSystemWindows to true, and it works. But it creates another layer that the GPU has to render... We had it working for two month but...

all changed when we seen the SystemBarTintManager library. It works like a charm! And also do the needed to not overstrees the GPU. Nice solution!

Comment: What if there is no layout, and the only content that is shown is of a dialog? Or when adding this will ruin the layout of the current Activity ? Look here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119517990

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be:

Add a Touch or Focus or ClickListener and move up the EditText holding layout up to half of the screen. However this is really not the way it should work, so keep your fingers crossed and hope that Google gets it fixed.

```
EditText e = new EditText(this);
    e.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus)
                v.animate().x(screenHeight/2f).start();
            else
                v.animate().x(screenHeight).start();
        }
    });
```

Just adjust v to your holding layout and make sure the positions you move to look good.

Comment: Thanks for the approach! Right now, we decided to launch the app without the translucent layout, so it's not necessary to patch the issue. No need to hurry for a translucent top bar... :)

Answer (score 0):

put this below lines after oncreate in you activity

```
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(mCategoryColors.getColorStatusBar());
    }
```

**Work for me :)**

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect solution but a workaround I found was to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Note that this will pan the whole window out of the way of the keyboard, rather than resizing it.

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) (search for `windowSoftInputMode`).

Answer (score 0):

set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` is ok. But i just want to say that it not work when activity is FullScreen, for more details see [Android How to adjust layout in Full Screen Mode when softkeyboard is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible)

Answer (score -1):

Add the following as well

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```