# how to make EditText work like Google keep app(smooth scroll and not covered by ime)?

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

I've got an Activity with fragment and there is an `EditText` inside that Fragment, I want to be able to write lines of text  but **software keyboard covers it** when `EditText` grows.

I've seen use of `ScrollView`, `adjustResize` and `adjustPan`, but i don't know why they did'n work!

## update:

if i use `.beginTransaction().add` it works fine but i need to use `.beginTransaction().replace` and keyboard covers `EditText`

## update 2:

it works fine on android 4.3
but in android 4.4 keyboard covers `EditText`

#### What I want:

1. A `layout(containing EditText)` that goes above keyboard when it comes up
2. `Smooth scroll` in that layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21245581/3473590), by setting `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on root element it works fine

Answer (score 1):

To force the soft keyboard to appear, you can use

```
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

To close it you can use

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: it's not what i meant.

My problem is that when keyboard comes up it covers EditText.

Comment: In your manifest file, you need to set the appropriate android:windowSoftInputMode property. This attribute is valid since API 3.

<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>

Comment: I've seen use of  adjustResize and adjustPan, but i don't know why they did'n work! i'll send my code soon.

Comment: <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity> Please use in your manifest activity tag

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of problem when you use translucent system bars. I had a similar problem and I found 0 solutions. Try to remove translucent system bars and check if it works fine.