# Android window doesn't resize/pan when softinput opened from WebView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

My problem is following.

1. Application uses theme `android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` and there is only one `Activity`, all other views are `Fragment`
2. I have `WebView` inside `ViewPager Fragment` which is inside `ScrollView`
3. HTML content has input fields
4. I click input field which is on bottom of `WebView`
5. Soft input opens, but the `Window` is not resized/panned

I've tried setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` or `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in my manifest for the `Activity`. Also tried setting one of those in java.

Normal `EditText` inside a `ScrollView` in my application does adjust pan properly so user can see where he/she is typing.

UPDATE:

If there is no working solution to get window adjust, is there a way to get `WebView` think it's content is like half screen height more bigger so user could at least scroll the input visible.

Comment: have you tried like this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"` ?

Comment: Same behavior, no help of that.

Comment: Niko two questions... are you using phonegap and what is the CSS for your body,html tags

Comment: This is pure Android and cannot 100% sure say the html, since it can change due to 3rd party web sites here.

Comment: Exactly my case. Same problem. Thank you for topic

Comment: @Niko: have you seen my answer ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay so this has been an issue from the very beginning and Google hasn't fixed it yet, maybe never. But from the the issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497 I found potential workaround for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19494006/1241783

I have overridden `WebView` and I simply added the code for it and it is working well enough to get the window adjusted. It is possible though the code doesn't always work because of various screen heights and might need some adjustments, but in many cases it is working okay and I go with that, since it's the only working solution I have seen.

Answer (score 4):

Try this `android:isScrollContainer="false"` in the ScrollView. According to the Android docx.

> Set this if the view will serve as a scrolling container, meaning that
>   it can be resized to shrink its overall window so that there will be
>   space for an input method

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I tried setting it to true for ScrollView and with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" flag set. Didn't work, also tried to set it false to ScrollView and true for WebView, no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what we have done to make it work.
As it is by design, FLAG_FULLSCREEN activity won't allow adjusting the views when a keyboard is visible, we took an approach with custom Keyboard Notification Listener and OnTouch listener of Webview.

[KeyboardHelper.java](https://gist.github.com/manwithsteelnerves/754220f3235567428c23188ab8b641e3) - to find out the keyboard visibility

[Webview Full-Screen Activity Adjustment](https://gist.github.com/manwithsteelnerves/f5084caab10733f2b26eae307c36f271#file-webview-full-screen-activity-adjustment) - To adjust the webview based on the notification and touch point.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the idea. Modified your code for my needs but overall this solution is a working one

Answer (score 1):

my code was also not able to resize when keyboard opens.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/simple_webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    />
```

i removed  (android:scrollbars="none") statement, and it worked ! So that means the app resizes itself only when the container is scrollable. so by default webview containers scrollable area internally.