# ScrollView does not work in fullscreen mode

Tags: android

In my app I am using the theme

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

and in my layout `android:fillViewport="true"` but the scroll is not working.
when I remove fullscreen -  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"` it is ok.
Any idea to solve this ?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nameFields"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/versionNumber"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textSize="15pt" />



                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/time_between_records"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/base_directory"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/continuous_mode"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/minIcpValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/minIcpValue"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/maxIcpValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/maxIcpValue"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/alarmsMode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/alarmsMode"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/clinicalMode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/clinicMode"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/trialID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/clinicId"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/snapShotMode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/snapshot_mode"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/screenShotMode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/screenshot_mode"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/enableTrialMode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/enableClinicalTrialScreen"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/monitorName"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


            </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't apply theme to remove action bar.

you have to remove action bar programtically like this before you set the contentview.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: change linearlayout height to fill parent.did you remove the theme from manifest?

Comment: the same result. yes i removed it

Comment: I found that it is a known issue
{link}(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible)