# Android Full Screen resize when soft input is shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fullscreen

I am developing an Android app in full screen mode. I want the screen automatically adjusted when a soft input is shown. I am using ScrollView to make my screen can extend larger than the maximum height. You can see the layout XML below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/taskdetail_bgvideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/taskdetail_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- Other Widgets -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The VideoView in the background is placed as intended to create a background video in the overall layout.

I tried the workaround in [Android How to adjust layout in Full Screen Mode when softkeyboard is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible) but somehow in my case, it doesn't work as expected. When I choose the bottommost TextView, all screen somehow pushed upwards to the top, leaving a very big black area between soft keyboard and the activity screen. Check the screenshot below (Sorry, still low reputation, so cannot post the image directly :( )

[Giant blackhole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElDAp.png)

So do you have any possible idea to tackle this weird behavior? In addition, I also have tried setting the softInputMode to ADJUST_RESIZE or ADJUST_PAN, and both settings did that. When I set it to ADJUST_NOTHING, nothing really adjusted at all.

When I don't use the workaround I mentioned above, I cannot scroll the view to the bottommost widget, but somehow the window view is panned to the focused TextView. I believe that this is actually the major culprit, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 9):

If you have the property `<item name="windowFullscreen">true</item>` in your theme then the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try change

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/taskdetail_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

to

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/taskdetail_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

Comment: Try this.. Put the ScrollView as root element, sounds like..

<ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

Answer (score -1):

Try to add below properties  to your `<activity tag declaration` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work as I expected. I don't want to pan the screen when the keyboard is shown. I want it to resize the activity screen size to the usable area above soft keyboard. But because the activity is in Full Screen, the adjustResize will not work.

Answer (score -1):

you have to write

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

in your manifest file