# Android App Pans even with adjustResize

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android app which operates in full screen mode and I need to have the activity re-size when the Soft Input comes up. Due to an android issue, this was not working event on specifying

```
android:softInputMode="adjustResize"
```

I adopted the work around provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19494006/1241783. Which works perfectly, and I am now able to re-size the app when the soft input comes up.

The issue is this: I have a LinearLayout containing an EditText control. When the text control gains access, soft input comes up, the app resizes and everything is fine. Except that android tries to keep the whole LinearLayout in the visible area and does a PAN of the app. I want to handle this myself and avoid doing this PAN. How can I achieve this? Please note that the activity softInputMode is set to adjustResize.

When I programmatically do this

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

Only then the PAN doesn't happen. But with this mode, even the resize doesn't happen.

Any resolution? Also, please help me understand why android would PAN my app when I have specifically asked for resize?