# Android SoftKeyboard hiding input field: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" not working?

Tags: android, cordova, uiscrollview, android-softkeyboard

In a PhoneGap application I am trying to show my input box using **adjustPan** not using adjustResize (as this is re sizing my whole view-HTML) and this is not working on some devices (>4.0 versions). Is there any specific solution for upper version, or should I find another way?

Here is my manifest description:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.AppDev"   android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="preferExternal">  
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>  


     <activity android:name=".AppDev" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> 
        </intent-filter>  
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.AppDev.SAppDev.NOTIFICATION"/>  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>
```

Answer (score -2):

Known issue with full screen apps in Android. Sorry.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497

-edit-
Here is a better solution, [Android How to adjust layout in Full Screen Mode when softkeyboard is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible/19494006#19494006)