# android scrollview not working when keyboard is showing

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I have problem in `ScrollView`.I have one layout,I use `ScrollView`  have one `Button` which is bottom at position.When I click `EditText` then keyboard is showing,my button moving up in my keyboard(`Button` witch is a bottom position use this `windowSoftInputMode` in my manifest file

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:theme="@style/NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
        >
```

and this is a my xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/upload_main_layout_upload"
            >
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/lay_v3"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/transfer_headerView_height"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:background="#f2f2f2"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/upload_header_layout">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/withdrow_change_card_width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/withdrow_change_card_height"
                        android:text="@string/u_slide_menu_change_card_v1"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_withdrow"
                        android:id="@+id/upload_choose_card_main"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:textColor="#4c4c4c"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size_small"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/u_common_margin_left"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/u_common_margin_left"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/withdrow_change_card_height"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_input_background_not_focus"
                        >


                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/u_common_margin_left"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            >
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_downarrow_grey"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:visibility="invisible"
                                android:padding="@dimen/slide_menu_hide_image"
                                />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/u_transfer_currency_layout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/u_widget_height"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            >

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/u_major_text"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                style="@style/u_edit_text"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size_extra_large"
                                android:hint="0.00"
                                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                                android:background="@null"


                                />

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/bootom_layout"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/u_common_margin_left"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/u_common_margin_left"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/u_done"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/u_widget_height"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_blue"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size"
                        android:text="@string/u_menu_upload" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/u_common_margin_left"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>
            </LinearLayout>



        </RelativeLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

i don't need to move botton button keyboard up.i want simple scroll when keyboard is showing.i also  tryed this in my manifest file but not working

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

what am i doing wrong? if anyone knows solution please help me thanks everyone

Comment: try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"

Comment: here is the working code... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible/44242034#44242034

Answer (score 0):

Add a ScrollView attribute:

```
android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

> Set this if the view will serve as a scrolling container, meaning that 
>    it can be resized to shrink its overall window so that there will be 
>    space for an input method.

If you set it to `false` then it won't resized to fit making room available for scrolling while keyboard is on screen.

Comment: Bottom position is not working means ? Keyboard is supposed to be above that bottom button, you have to scroll down to Touch it..