# adjustPan and adjustResize in nested fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

I use a ViewPager and inside the first fragment of the ViewPager I have a another fragment that is parenting a sub fragment with ScrollView in it. to make it more visual:

```
┌------------┐
|   1        | 1 is the ViewPager fragment
| ┌---------┐|
| | 2       || 2 is the fragment inside ViewPager fragment
| |┌-------┐||
| ||3      ||| 3 is the sub fragment containing the ScrollView with EditText form
| ||form   |||
| ||here   |||
| ||       |||
| |└-------┘||
| └---------┘|
└------------┘
```

**Issue is:**

when I use `adjustResize` it allows me to scroll the fragment 3 `ScrolView` till end but when screen is too small, the `ScrollView` hides behind the `SoftKeyboard` and it does not push the parent fragments up to display fragment 3.

when I use `adjustPan` in small screens it pushes the the parent fragments up and allows me to see the 'fragment 3' but when I scroll, some of the `ScrollView` hides behind the soft keyboard.

I have done some reading in `SO` and android docs. they all point at using `AdjustResize` with `ScrollView`. but in my case i need to push the parent fragments up in small screens, otherwise the `ScrollView` in fragment3 will be covered by `SoftKeyboard`.

is it possible to do adjustPan in parent fragment and adjustResize for child fragment with scrollview at the same time ? if not is there any workarounds?

**your helps are appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

Test `"stateHidden|adjustResize"` for parent activity.For me, It was the only way to over come a situation like yours

Comment: as mentioned in the `OP` I have tried using adjustResize. but when the device has a small screen the `ScrollView` hides behind `softKeyboard`

Comment: Yeah I noticed but I didn't get that you have used  `"stateHidden|adjustResize"` as exactly as same and both together

Comment: yes I have. and they refer to two different states. my issue is the adjustResize is not effecting the two parent fragments. I need to use AdjustPan for parent fragments to move them up. but meanwhile i need  AdjustResize for ScrollView.

Comment: If you don't mind, please put the working alone part of your code so I can figure out how it could be fixed.

Comment: Adbi her is a link to my [Github Repo](https://github.com/pouriabagheri/ScrollViewAdjustViewPager)
thanks for you kind attention