# Android SnackBar above keyboard with FAB

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button, android-snackbar, coordinator-layout

I have a problem with my app: a strange behavior on Version >= Lollipop, due to AndroidBug5497Workaround.

I'm using coordinator layout, collapsing toolbar, fragments, floating action buttons and snackbar, everything works fine on pre-lollipop.
I need to show my Fab over keyboard, and I use the AndroidBug5497Workaround. (according with [Joseph Johnson's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible/19494006#19494006))

But with this solution the snackbar is getting crazy.
I'm using all android's support libraries 23.2.+, and in my manifest I've set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"` for this activity

That's the structure of my activity :

```
<Coordinator Layout>
    <Collapsing Toolbar />
    <Linear Layout>
       <Fragment />
    </Linear Layout>
    <Floating Action Button />
</Coordinator Layout>
```

And that's the fragment:

```
<Linear Layout>
    <Nested Scroll View>
        <Linear Layout>
            <CardView 1/>
            <CardView 2/>
            <CardView n/>
        </Linear Layout>    
    </Nested Scroll View>
</Linear Layout>
```

Any help will be appreciate.
Thanks a lot.

[image: Normal Behavior without keyboard]

[image: Pre Lollipop Behavior]
[image: Lollipop]

Comment: I face same issue, if you got the solution then please share it here?

Comment: no. I used dialogs to "solve" the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try using following in the activity of your manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```