# Soft keyboard overlaps EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat when AppTheme is Translucent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

## Using

- latest **V14 Preference Support Library**.
- **Translucent Theme** on API > 19
- **EditTextPreferenceCompat** inside **PreferenceFragmentCompat**

## Problem

Tapping on **EditTextPreferenceCompat** is followed by popping **EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat** with controls overlapped by soft keyboard which is wrong:

[image]

- If i use *non* Translucent Theme or API < 19 - everything is fine.
- If i use normal **DialogFragment** *with* Translucent Theme - everything is fine.

## What did i try?

- https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix library
- Manually setting window's adjust_resize/adjust_pan (but i think it doesn't work for Translucent/Fullscreen)
- Disabling/Enabling Translucent. It works but that = is not an option for me.

#### Any workaround for this?

Comment: The translucent theme is messing up here. maybe try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible

Comment: @R.Zagórski normal DialogFragments work well with Translucent Theme - so i think it is related only to V14 implementation

Comment: @localhost maybe the Translucent Theme are overriding the onConfigurationChanged. This behaviour usually happens when you override the onConfigurationChanged. Can you create a repository on github with the code that shows the bug? So I can make some tests.

Answer (score 0):

Translucent/Fullscreen can cause adjust_resize not working.If you get the height of soft keyboard can help you solve the problem,you can change the view's height by soft keyboard's height. However,google doesn't open the api of getting the height of soft keyboard.One way is that you set a view tree listener.

Answer (score 0):

Have same problem.

Just try add to AppTheme this line

```
<item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog</item>
```

or via setStyle method in your DialogFragment.

You can choose any other dialog theme that u want.