# Adjust resize not working in immersive mode

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-immersive, adjustpan

I need my app to be in immersive mode always(Hide nav bar and status bar). The issue is when I show a dialog, even if I set the setSoftInputMode to SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE / SOFT_INPUT_ADJUSTPAN, the dialog window is not adjusted on softkeyboard. Some text on top of the dialog gets cut off.

```
dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
         hideSystemUi1(dialog.getWindow().getDecorView());

        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

How can this issue be fixed?

Comment: It is android system bug.
See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible