# How to adjust softkeyboard when navigation input is hiding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, android-fullscreen, android-immersive

## The problem

When I'm in [fullscreen / immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/immersive) and when the softkeyboard is shown I have some empty space which could be used to display more information to the end user, the empty space took the place of the navigation buttons.

### Without the navigation bar

[image: screenshot without the navigation shown]

### With the navigation bar

[image: screenshot with the navigation shown]

## What I've tried

Following some comments/answers here on stackoverflow, I tried to:

- Add to my manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` inside the activity tag.
- Using the class [SoftInputAssist.java](https://gist.github.com/grennis/2e3cd5f7a9238c59861015ce0a7c5584) of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19494006/9702804)

## My goal

I want to be able to move the keyboard down so that no unused space is wasted.