# Android RadioGroup

Tags: android, radio-group

I am developing an application. The problem is that when i click on last radio button on my activity it shows keyboard popup(which is my requirement) but i dont want the radio buttons to be up on the keyboard.They should be at bottom of the layout were they are.i have uploaded 2 photos.[image: Image 1]
[image: Image2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check  **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000795/android-keyboared-overlaps-with-the-edittext-with-printscreens/8103047#8103047)** question,For Same problem,I have written one another solution there,hope this helps you..

Comment: i tried this one too but its not working for me.