# Layout should go up when soft keyboard came in front of view in Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a problem that I have a login Screen in which when we click on Edit Text the SoftInput Keyboard override the two widgets One is TextView and another is Login Button which are in Relative Layout, but I want when we select any Edit Text the whole Relative layout should goes Up and all widgets are visible above the softinput Keyboard of Android default. Please suggest me for the right solution.

Thanks in advance.

**My Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ffffff">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/logo" >
</ImageView>
    </FrameLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/login_box_bg"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_height="220dip" android:layout_marginTop="20dip">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/ed_Login_Email"
            android:background="@drawable/login_input_bg" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:hint="Email:" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="text" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        </EditText>
        <EditText android:background="@drawable/login_input_bg" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/ed_Login_Pwd"
            android:inputType="textPassword" android:hint="Password:" android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="50dip" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        </EditText>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_Login_RememberUnchecked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/checkbox_unchkd_large" android:layout_gravity="top|left" android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginTop="100dip" android:clickable="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Login_RememberMeUnchecked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Remember Me" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_gravity="top|left" android:layout_marginLeft="35dip" android:layout_marginTop="102dip" android:clickable="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Login_Login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Login_RememberMeUnchecked"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_btn_bg"
            android:text="LOG IN"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Login_ForgotPwd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Forgot your password?"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Please refer below images for more understanding:

[image]

[image]

I have tried with android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" but nothing happens, problem remains same.

Comment: can this hep you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000795/android-keyboared-overlaps-with-the-edittext-with-printscreens

Comment: check out the different softinputmodes for the edittext

Comment: How we check different softinput modes?

Answer (score 10):

Please change the windows soft input mode to Resize , To change the mode to “resize” add the following statement to your activity in AndroidManifest file.

```
<activity android:name="YourActivityName" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Comment: The user said he has already tried `adjustResize`.  Why are you telling him again?