# Soft keyboard covers an EditText in a PopupWindow

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I've thrown together a simple test project that displays a PopupWindow containing an EditText (on Android 2.2). When I tap the EditText, the soft keyboard is shown, as I would expect. However, the soft keyboard covers the EditText, and I cannot get the screen to pan to keep the EditText in view in the way I would have thought it should. My code:

TestAdjustPanActivity.java:

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

public class TestAdjustPanActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(this);
        pw.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null, false));
        pw.setWidth(400);
        pw.setHeight(600);
        pw.setFocusable(true);

        pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        pw.setTouchable(true);
        pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

        // This is the line referred to in the edit:
        pw.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

        findViewById(R.id.main).post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.main), Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

popup.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#666666"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/current_password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

...and my AndroidManifest.xml does contain the line `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan"` in the tag for the one and only activity in the app.

Any ideas? None of the other posts on SO related to this issue have done it for me. What am I missing that's keeping the view from panning the way I would expect it to?

EDIT: I tried adding a line in TestAdjustPanActivity as indicated, which caused the screen to pan perfectly on an Android 3.2 device I have. However, it still doesn't pan on my Android 2.2 device, which makes this even more confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this in the future, I ended up just using a Dialog instead of a PopupWindow, and panning to keep the EditText in view works fine on 2.2 with a Dialog.

Answer (score 3):

There is simpler way. Just provide alternative layout for active keyboard.

1. Left click on project select: "Android tools/New Resource File..." .
2. Chose layout, give file name "main" (don't worry about conflicts).
3. Click "next". Then on list on the left select "keyboard" and move it to right (click "->").
4. On right side select keyboard state.
5. Click finish.
6. Now copy content of your main.xml located in "res/layout" to new file in res/layout-keyssoft".
7. Correct new layout in such way that keyboard is not in that way. Remember to maintain same "id"s for respective components in those two layouts (that is why copy paste was needed).
8. Enjoy how it works

Read about [configuration changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) to understand how it works. Note that EVERY configuration change (orientation change, language change, ...) will cause recreation of Activity (in such case argument of onCreate is not null) so you can provide different layouts for different cases.

Comment: According to the Android docs, this only works for when the actual availability of a keyboard changes, not for when it is simply shown or hidden, unfortunately. They do mention however the keyboardHidden property of the Configuration class, which I'll take a look at. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the problem is because of using that `ScrollView` in `XML`,

There has been another problem similar to this, You can [check all different answers there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000795/android-keyboared-overlaps-with-the-edittext-with-printscreens), and may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan"
```

to

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

only in your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan
```

to

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Comment: Meh, no luck unfortunately. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

It took couple of hours to figure out and I ended up using **scrollview**.

Apparently there is no way to overcome this problem when you use popup window and soft input keypad hide your view. Just go for Scroll View.