# Android keyboard cut EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I have a vertical scrollview which contains multiple textView.

At the bottom i got a EditText, just lika a messagin application.
I seted in my manifest android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan".

The problem is that when I tap on editText my layout goes up which is good but the keyboard cut my editText in half like in the picture.

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:background="#CCCCCC" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical" >
           //many textView
          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_area"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#168191" />

          </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/send_msg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:background="#CCDEDC"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textColor="#168191"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_msg_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#CCCCCC"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: printscreen]

Comment: I think you will have to put the LinearLayout with EditText and Button into the scrollview as well. They are not under Scrollview tag, so "adjustPan" is not working for them.

Comment: You need to check all the answers given to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000795/android-keyboared-overlaps-with-the-edittext-with-printscreens). And you will surely found one solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Add to AndroidManifest.xml following option to the activity you want to see "not-cutted" text by keyboard. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"`

**UPD**
May be you need change padding of your edittext style, because seems it is custom one.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added "android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" and removed left padding but I still have the same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

use 
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
in actvity tag of your manifest.
It will show all of your view above the softKeyboard.