# push only scrollview while keyboard open android

Tags: android

Hi I have Activity which contain 3 view

```
-RelativeLayout
---TextView                 1)
---ScrollView               2)
-----FrameLayout
---------ListView
---------EditText -----------> When I click over here (2) view only pushup
---TextView                 3)
```

I want only **2) which is scrollview** should pushup when keyboard open, but right now it push **TextView 3)** also

I have tried with in menifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
or
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" 
or
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

but nothing happens, 3) textview also pushes with 2) Scrollview

Comment: @Apurva no bro still not :( if you find any solution then please tell me

Comment: How do you have two views inside a FrameLayout? I thought a FrameLayout can only hold one view.

Comment: Can you align `3)` with bottom?

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8103047/903469 ?

Comment: do you want TextView (3) to hide behind the keyboard ?

Comment: Does your scrollview have fillViewport set to true?

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit what exactly worked for you...please let me know...as I am facing the same trouble, referred [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32095820/1479511).

Comment: Hi @DroidWormNarendra I have accepted Evripidis Drakos's answer because it is the only best way , in that I have hide that button when keyboard opening

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Opening the soft keyboard reduces the available screen space, it doesnt change the fact that the TextView 3) is at the bottom of the screen.

So, if I understand correctly you want to not display the TextView 3) when you open the keyboard?

If that's so, you could try using this method [here](http://felhr85.net/2014/05/04/catch-soft-keyboard-showhidden-events-in-android/) to capture the showing/hiding of the soft keyboard and show/hide the Textview.

*EDIT*
Also try using `android:isScrollContainer="false"` on the scrollview with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` or `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Comment: It should be, though it could depend on target api (haven't tested it myself on newer apis) but it's not so difficult to test it yourself :)

Answer (score 3):

what you can do is to detect the keyboard if it is showing hide the text view and id not then show it

here is a piece of code

```
_Your_Text_View.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    Rect r = new Rect();
                    // r will be populated with the coordinates of your view
                    // that area still visible.
                    activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                    heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView()
                                .getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);


                if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than100 pixels, its
                            // probably a keyboard...

                    //here hide your TextView
                }else{

                         //here Show your TextView
                }
            });
```

also write that piece of code in you menifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys i fell into the same issue and got refuge through a very handy and easiest solution that involves putting an attribute in your **Scrollview** tag residing in your xml file. That is

```
android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

This prenvents the bottom layout to sit on the keyboard. Hope it resolves the issue.