# Keyboard overlapping EditText on click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-keypad

In my fragment I have an editText inside a scrollview and when I click on that I set it to open like this:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

It works fine from the first time it opens, but when I close the keyboard and open it again, it overlaps the editText, how can I set the editText to always open in SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN mode?

the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/alabaster">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/semconexao"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Verifique sua conexão com a internet"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible">



                <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageInst"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <com.retornar.utils.CircledNetworkImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/logo_maior"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_maior"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop">

                </com.retornar.utils.CircledNetworkImageView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/more"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_amp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/retornarTitulo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageInst"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/retornarTitulo"
                android:textColor="@color/armadillo"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text2" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/retornarTitulo"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/retornar"
                android:textColor="@color/armadillo"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text1" />

            <include layout="@layout/valores" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/campovalor"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shadoweditext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="ou entre com um valor"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@color/gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/propText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Propósito em destaque"
                android:textColor="@color/armadillo"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text2"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <include layout="@layout/inst_prop" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/maisprop"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_proposito"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/maisproptext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Mais propósitos"
                android:textColor="@color/armadillo"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ret"
        fontPath="fonts/Avenir-Bold.ttf"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:alpha="0.9"
        android:background="@color/blumine"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="DOAR"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think you need to add scrollview as parent of layout.after may your code work. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000795/android-keyboard-overlaps-with-the-edittext-with-printscreens) link helps you

Comment: Have you tried setting it in the manifest?

Comment: @zgc7009 how can I do that using a fragment?

Comment: You probably can set it on the activity on which the fragment is added.

Comment: @EdsonMenegatti ok I just did that, but from the second time I click on the editText the keyboard overlaps it

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What about setting `RESIZE` instead of `PAN`? You will be able to keep your `EditText` above the `SoftKeyboard`. Try as follows:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

However, instead of doing this at runtime, you can set it in the `manifest` as an `Activity` *(parent)* attribute. This will also be handled in your fragment *(child)*:

```
<activity
    android:name=".NameActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize">
```

Then, as you can see, the `EditText` is above the SoftKeyboard, but from your layout, you have a `TextView` with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` attribute which will overlap the `EditText`:

[image: 1_screenshot_overlap_resize]

To prevent this behaviour, just set the `ScrollView` above the last `TextView` as follows:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ret"> <!-- instead of "footer" -->
```

And you will get the following result:

[image: 2_screenshot_no_overlap_resize]

Comment: @Filo why doesn't same code not working in BottomSheetFragment  by calling  *getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);* in Oncreateview

Answer (score 23):

Try this, add this code in your AndroidManifest.xml activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```