# SoftKeyboard overlaps over EditText - ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-constraintlayout, soft-keyboard

I created a Registration form using ConstraintLayout. 
This contains vertical stack of EditText fields. 
The top three EditTexts are displaying fine and I can type them while the SoftKeyboard is visible. However, for other EditText fields, they completely got hidden behind the SoftKeyboard.

Following is my Layout XML file in which I'm facing this issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context="com.RegisterWithEmailActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtRegFirstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hintName"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtRegUserName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtRegFirstName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtRegPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hintPassword"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtRegUserName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtStreetAddress1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hintStreetAdd1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtRegPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtStreetAddress2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hintStreetAdd2"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtStreetAddress1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtCity"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hintCity"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.247"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtStreetAddress2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtState"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hintState"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.116"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edtCity"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtStreetAddress2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtZipCode"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="188dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hintZipCode"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtCity" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtGender"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hintGender"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.875"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edtZipCode"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtState" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtRegEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtGender" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegisterWithEmail"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorLoginButton"
        android:elevation="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="REGISTER"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtRegEmailAddress" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is AndroidManifest.xml snippet with some tweaks applied for SoftKeyboard.

```
<activity
            android:name=".RegisterWithEmailActivity"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"></activity>
```

Comment: Possible duplication? https://stackoverflow.com/q/33109976/8713068. 
In the accepted answer there is a suggestion to adjust `android:windowSoftInputMode` in AndroidManifest and add `ScrollView` in your layout.

Comment: Don't use `adjustResize` and `adjustPan` together. Try with `adjustPan` only.

Comment: I already tried with "adjustPan" also. But it's not working in my case.

Comment: Put Constraint Layout inside a ScrollView and set windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize only

Answer (score 0):

> Try using Scrollview with only one child layout. and then place your edit text's and buttons under that child layout.