# Soft Keboard covers up TextInputEditText inside a fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with 2 TextInputEditText. When my activity starts, the soft keyboard covers part of my input, and when clicking NEXT on the keyboard the focus passes to the second input that is completely covered by the keyboard. It´s possible to see what has been typed only when I close the keyboard.

[image]

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@drawable/back_gradient"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/DP10"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_new_course_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/SP22"
    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
    android:text="@string/newCourse"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="@dimen/SP26"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>


<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/LoginTextInputLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/DP20"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/DP20"
    android:hint="@string/courseName">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_new_course_name"
        style="@style/LoginTextInputEditStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_new_course_acronym"
        />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/LoginTextInputLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/DP20"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/DP20"
    android:hint="@string/acronym">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_new_course_acronym"
        style="@style/LoginTextInputEditStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_save_course"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/DP40"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/DP10"
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:textColor="@color/color_ok"
    app:cornerRadius="@dimen/DP15"
    app:strokeColor="@color/color_ok"
    app:strokeWidth="@dimen/DP2" />
```

The same layout works fine if inflated on an activity, but here it´s a fragment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard overlapping EditText on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109976/keyboard-overlapping-edittext-on-click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to remove the problem:

**Process 1**

Use a `ScrollView` as  the root layout and put all the other layouts inside it.

**Process 2** *(recommended)*

Use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` in your manifest file.
More detail about this is [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371938/proper-way-to-handle-android-studios-nullpointerexception-lint-warning)

Answer (score 1):

please add this in your activity attribute in the manifest

```
<activity android:name="Your_Activity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" ></activity>
```