# Android Softkeyboard hiding textfield inside webview

Tags: android-softkeyboard

Inside a RelativeLayout I have a header layout and then webview.
The web view hav a html text field which gets hidden by the soft keyboard.

Comment: And... what? What would you prefer? What are you asking? In order to answer your question, we need to know what it is first.

Comment: when i click html input text field then the softkeyboard comes up. and its ajustpan attribute doesnot works