# Show webview's input text when keyboard focuses on it

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

I have an input text in webview, it is at the lower parts of screen. My problem is when user touches that input text, keyboard is opened over it and edit text becomes invisible. How can I solve this?

Comment: Actually WebView itself will try to scroll the page in your case, so that the input box won't be covered by the IME (keyboard) UI. What's your HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my problem was with full screen activity. It is a bug I guess.

[adjustPan not preventing keyboard from covering EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558810/adjustpan-not-preventing-keyboard-from-covering-edittext)