# Why isn't my view resizing when I show the keyboard?

Tags: android

I've got a very basic webview app, and this is the `layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the manifest I have:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

In the page I load, there is an input at the bottom of the page. When I click it, the keyboard shows, but obscures it. It's *not* a case of the view shrinking but not scrolling, as I can't scroll the webview to show the input with the keyboard visible. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it still resize? Maybe you can use `adjustPan` to move it so that the focused area is visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug with WebViews in fullscreen apps. [More information in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558810/adjustpan-not-preventing-keyboard-from-covering-edittext), but I fixed it by making my app non-fullscreen.