# Listview does not have scroll bar when edittext has focus

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, focus

I have a listview and a edittext which are sequentially holded on vertical linear layout with weight values 0.9 to 0.1 in a dialoglayout. When I tap on edittext keyboard appears and layout moves to top but listview scrollbar does not change. Thus I can not see upper items of listview. How can I fix it ?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:bootstrapbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fontawesometext="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listPMs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapEditText
        android:id="@+id/editPMAddMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:hint="@string/hintEnterMessage"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        bootstrapbutton:be_roundedCorners="true"
        bootstrapbutton:be_state="primary" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in manifest this:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21293762/3864698

Comment: It did not help. It is a dialog in a fragment with listview and edittext. Dialog title goes out of the screen.