# android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" is not working

Tags: android, keyboard

I have silly problem please follow the below pics

[image]

And when i clicked on Enter Email it saw like below pic,

[image]

Now the problems are coming inspite of using **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** android Lollipop theme and toolbar,

1. Image became smaller.
2. Email edittext should have shown above keyboard, but it did not.

Suggest some solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all make sure you have provided a `ScrollView` in your xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >  
...

...

</ScrollView>
```

Then inside your `activity` make sure you are doing something like this(this code is just to demonstrate where to use `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);`) :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.temp);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    final EditText time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.timeET);
    time.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            time.requestLayout();
            MyActivity.this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_UNSPECIFIED);

            return false;
        }
    });
    final EditText date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dateET);
    date.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            date.requestLayout();
            MyActivity.this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_UNSPECIFIED);

            return false;
        }
    });
     }
```

Comment: You should use `match_parent` only. `fill_parent` is deprecated now.

Comment: Glad it helped you @CloyMonis

Comment: in second `OnTouchListener` it should probably be `date.requestLayout();` instead of `time.requestLayout();` - http://i.stack.imgur.com/K6eGC.png

Comment: what about toolbar :/ which need not to be scrolled

Answer (score 7):

Set the `configChanges` attribute in your manifest as follows

```
<activity
    android:name="com.xyz.activityName"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"/>
```

No need to add `adjustPan` anywhere -neither in the manifest, nor with the individual views and neither programmatically.

It never lets the input field hide behind the softkeyboard.

Comment: This is the correct answer. No need of `ScrollView` and no need of `adjustPan`. The `configChanges` just does the job.

Comment: Not working with fullscreen even when layout is in ScrollView. Sadly, none of these answers work.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure `windowFullscreen` isn't included in the theme. Check `values\Styles.xml` for the same.

If you need the full screen, then create another theme with same attributes except `windowFullscreen` and use it for the required activity.

In `Manifest.xml` use `adjustResize` instead of `adjustPan`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33370845/2820534)

Comment: What if I don't want to lose the windowFullScreen?

Comment: @Senhor `windowFullScreen` and `ScrollView` aren't cooperating each other.

Answer (score 2):

I also add "adjustNothing".
My activity in AndroidManifest.xml is something like this:

```
...
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan|adjustNothing">
</activity>
...
```

It worked for me. Please try yourself.

Answer (score 1):

just add in android manifest.xml

```html
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing">
</activity>
```