# Android:windowSoftInputMode='adjustPan' is not working in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

I'm having the Flash content that is loading inside the web-view.

The content is loading perfectly. But my problem is, inside the Flash content I have embedded text-fields.

When I tapped on the text-fields, the virtual keyboard is covering those fields. So I added the "`adjustPan`" tag in my manifest and have also tried the "adjustResize" tag. But none of them is not working fine.

Can anybody please give me a suggestion, how to resolve this?

Comment: this should work --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/27854129/12553303