# Keyboard covers Exidtext field

Tags: android, android-edittext

The Edittext field is covered with the current keyboard. 
People don't see what they are typing at the moment. The page is a fragment.

Here is a XML layout of the mentioned Edittext:

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/commentEditText"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:hint="Opmerkingen" />
```

It doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing it the wrong way. Can you help me to solve it?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmuXm.png

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your activity tag in Menifest file,

```
 <activity 
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"/>
```

Comment: I add the adjustPan to the correct Activity but it didn't work. mweh..

Comment: I solved it to a ScrollView!

Answer (score 0):

use  `android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustPan`  in mainfiest file inside activity

use like this see example

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activity"


        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden">

    </activity>
```

Comment: The code is in a Fragment no activity. How do I do that in the manifest?

Comment: fragment is also part of activity so use this in activity is will work on fragement too use same code in your same activity which r using fragement

Comment: I add the adjustPan to the correct Activity but it didn't work. mweh..

Comment: refer this   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854029/androidwindowsoftinputmode-adjustpan-is-not-working

Comment: I Solved it to ad a ScrollView

Comment: congest please dont ask  duplicate question you will get minus

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your activity's manifest file,  which will resize your screen to fit keyboard.

If user still cannot see input on EditText you can try `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, which does not resize screen to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing.

Comment: The code is in a Fragment no activity. How do I do that in the manifest?

Comment: Your fragment is associated with an activity right? Add this in that activity

Comment: I add the adjustPan to the correct Activity but it didn't work. mweh..

Comment: I Solved it to ad a ScrollView