# Recycleview child covered by keyboard

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-softkeyboard

I have an activity that has RecycleView.
Child of this RecycleView contain radio buttons in radioGroup, where when last radio buttons selected it show the EditText.
this is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout>
<Toolbar/>

<RelativeLayout
width:match_parent
height:match_parent>
    <RecycleView
    width:match_parent
    height:match_parent
    above:footer/>
    <LinearLayout
      id:footer
      width:match_parent
      height:wrap_content>
       <Button/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem happen when I scroll down to last child. It covered by keyboard.

This is the layout of each cell:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <RadioGroup/>
  <EditText/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have try to use "AdjustResize", that should resize the ui when keyboard appears. But the last child still covered.
Has anyone have other solution?

Comment: Please provide the whole code, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution from this post [Look the honeal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4789886/2128847).
So basicly you can't set activity to fullscreen (in your theme) while use "AdjustResize"

Answer (score 0):

try `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`